# Long-lasting groovy compilation in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin, compilation

I'm having problem with compiling groovy project in eclipse. It takes about 15-20 mins. to compile 13 groovy files. It seems like there is some kind of loop or what. When I run maven build, I did not even notice - it took several secs, but when building workspace in eclipse its horrible. I'm using eclipse indigo (but same problem is in juno), groovy compiler ver. 2.6.0-01 and groovy ver. 1.8.6.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Upvote, because it was taking ages for me too!

Comment: Can you post the project somewhere? Are there AST transforms in the mix?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. How do I know if there are any AST transforms?

Comment: I have upgraded groovy eclipse plugin and set groovy compiler version on project to 2.1.2 (from 1.8.6) and works well!
Thanks anyway!
P.S. The 2.6.0-01 ver. was maven plugin which works well and 1.8.6 was groovy eclipse plugin compiler ver.

Comment: After I've upgraded my eclipse indigo to kepler, it was possible to download groovy ver. 2.x.x and after that, the problem has gone :) Solved!